# CoreData + UITableView, Messages.app replica

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I need to create uitableview like in messages.app. Data loading through NSFetchedResultsController from CoreData.

I found the easiest way to do this, really i don't find this method in google :)

the magic code:

For UITableView and UITableViewCell:

```
CGAffineTransform transform1 = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform1, -1.0, 1.0);
```

Then i use custom "header", but because our UITableView is mirrored and rotated it will be footer:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0;
}
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 20.0;
}
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableVie viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    MessagesSectionHeaderView *vieww = [[MessagesSectionHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20)];
    vieww.text = [self tableView:tableVie titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    return vieww;
}
```

it works like a charm without any animation troubles.

But. What troubles can be when i do this trick? Maybe slower scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

No troubles. The transform should not affect the scrolling in the least.

I find this solution a bit hacky because it is not really necessary to rotate the table view in order to get the reverse scrolling effect. But if it works for you, go for it!

Comment: How can i do this without rotating? i don't find any normal working code.

Comment: You can scroll the table view in any direction, up or down. You can scroll a collection view in all 4 directions.